# Syntactic restriction in function vs. function template when passing an address

Tags: c++, templates

Let's assume we want to print out the attribute of an arbitrary class through two different functions: One function takes a parameter `const Widget&`, the other one is a function template that takes a parameter of type `const T&`. We pass one argument of type `Widget` and `Widget&` respectively. The code can look like the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Widget {
public:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Widget &w ) { 
        output << "Attr : " << w.attr;
        return output;            
    }
private:
    int attr = 5;
};

void f(const Widget& param) {
  std::cout << param << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void f2(const T& param) {
  std::cout << param << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Widget> arg = {Widget()};
    if (!arg.empty()) {
        f(arg[0]);
        //f(&arg[0]);   <-- This leads to a compile time error.
        f2(arg[0]);
        f2(&arg[0]); // <-- In contrast, why does this work if the above fails?
    }
}
```

Why can we pass an address as argument in the function template, but not in the function? What is `T` in both valid cases?

Output:

```
Attr : 5
Attr : 5
0x55feee619eb0
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The unary `&` operator is the *pointer.-to* operator. The result of `&arg[0]` have the type `Widget*`. The function `f` want a `const Widget&` argument. References and pointers are not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I realized that. Does `&arg[0]` leads to a difference `T` in contrast to `arg[0]`? In "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers, the author says that references in the argument to a function template taking a reference or pointer are ignored when determining `T` (12th Release, Item 1, p. 11, print version). I do not quite understand what the difference is in both cases and why `Widget*` can be passed into the template when these ignoring-of-reference-rules hold.

Comment: `&` in an expression and `&` in a type have nothing to do with each other. The symbol is just reused for two completely distinct meanings. `&` in a type indicates a _reference_, but `&` in an expression forms a _pointer_. Pointers and references are also completely distinct concepts.

Comment: @RCal "_references in the argument_": There is no reference in the argument. And the statement should be even more general: Expressions never have a reference type. They only have value category (which does matter to some degree in template argument deduction, but the author is probably simplifying here for the purpose of introduction). `Widget*` is not a reference type.

Comment: In the call `f2(arg[0])` the type of `T` will be `Widget`. In the call `f2(&arg[0])` the type of `T` will be `Widget*`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I also did need the comment of Sam Varshavchik to fully grasp your comment. I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is not a reference. A reference is not a pointer. `arg[0]` evaluates to a reference to an object. `&arg[0]` evaluates to a pointer to the object. That's what the unary `&` operator does: it produces a pointer to some object.

The function takes a reference to an object as its parameter, and not a pointer. That's the reason for the compilation error.

As far as the template is concerned, the template parameter gets deduced to be a pointer to an object, and the instantiated template's parameter is a reference to a pointer. The instantiated template's parameter is a `Widget * const &`, a reference to a `const` pointer to a `Widget`.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks a lot! I did not realize that even references to pointer are valid.

Comment: An (arguably) improvement to `f2` could be `template<typename T> void f2(T const& param) { if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>) { if (param) std::cout << *param << "\n"; else std::cout << "(null)" << "\n"; } else { std::cout << param << "\n"; } }`

Comment: In C++ any object can have a reference or a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

In this function template:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void f2(const T& param)
```

The template parameter can turn into any value which you can take a reference from, whether it's `Widget` itself or pointer to it `Widget*`. While your `f` function:

```cpp
void f(const Widget& param)
```

Can take a reference to `Widget` type only and at the same time you are trying to pass a value type (to be precise a reference to the value type, but they act the same in this context) and a pointer to the value type here (which are definitely not the same thing):

```
f(arg[0]);
f(&arg[0]);
```

You may want to introduce another overload in order to make it work, where the parameter type would be a pointer:

```cpp
void f(Widget const *const param);
```

Comment: Thanks providing great examples. Even though I have already marked the above answer as accepted, your examples have once again clarified a few things. The overload also makes things clearer.

Comment: @RCal no worries, only OP can decide which answer should be accepted, and since [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75965037/5690248) came in 1 minute prior mine, I think your decision is fair